# Finding Duplicate numbers in a sorted Array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I want to know if there is a any way to find out how many pairs is in a sorted array
The easiest way is using two for loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
```

But the point is this two for loops works even in unsorted array
if our array is sorted is there any way to find the pairs with only one for or while loop?
example can be {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3} it have 4 pairs [0][1], [0][2], [1][2], [4][5]

Comment: In the sorted array you only need to compare the adjacent elements. Only one loop is needed.

Comment: Please clarify the title: duplicates and "pairs" are not the same thing.  Also how many pairs does: `1 2 2 2 3' have?

Comment: @Andy in your example it have 3 pairs index [1] [2] , [1] [3], [2][3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to walk over the array and count the consecutive identical numbers. If you encounter a different number, then you need to calculate the number of pairs for the last seen number. For each different number, you need to do this.

In the image below, you see that there are three *subsequences* of identical numbers.

```
     a      b    c
  ┌──┴──┐  ┌┴─┐  │
  │     │  │  │  │
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 ]
```

Let's first define a method to calculate the number of pairs for a specific count. Its formula is always

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀² − 
()⠀=⠀─────
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀2

```java
int countPairs(int number) {
    return number * (number - 1) / 2;
}
```

Then let's write the method to walk over the array. I have added comments within the code to explain what happens:

```java
int countPairs(int[] array) {
    // If our array is empty or contains a single element, then there are no
    // pairs, obviously
    if (array.length < 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    // We keep track of the total number of pairs here
    int totalPairs = 0;

    // We also keep track of the number of consecutive identical numbers.
    int consecutive = 1;

    // We begin our index with 1, since we need to compare it to the previous one
    // (and we don't want an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException to be thrown)
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == array[i - 1]) {
            // If the encountered number is the same as the previous one,
            // then increment the subsequence counter
            consecutive++;
        }
        else {
            // If the number is different than the previous one, then a new subsequence
            // has started. We need to process the previous subsequence. Calculate the
            // number of pairs, add it to the result, and then reset `consecutive`
            totalPairs += countPairs(consecutive);
            consecutive = 1;
        }
    }
    // At last, process the last sequence
    totalPairs += countPairs(consecutive);
    return totalPairs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have to compare every element with every other (what 2 nested for-loops do), but only the neighbouring ones...

```
int paires = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.lenght - 1; i++) {
   if(arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) paires++; // Test if the i-th element is equal to the i+1-th element and increasing counter if so.
}
```

Note that for-loop only runs up to the n - 1 element, otherwise there will be a null-pointer exeption

Comment: It returns 3 for `arr = {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3}`, not 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static int combination(int start, int end) {
    int size = end - start;
    return size * (size - 1) / 2;
}

static int countDuplicatedNumberPairs(int[] arr) {
    int length = arr.length, count = 0;
    if (length <= 0) return count;
    int start = 0, previous = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i)
        if (arr[i] != previous) {
            count += combination(start, i);
            start = i;
            previous = arr[i];
        }
    count += combination(start, length);
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr =  {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3} ;
    System.out.println(countDuplicatedNumberPairs(arr));
}
```

output:

```
4
```